# Square GridLayout with square children (side=parent width)

Tags: java, android, android-gridlayout

- I am trying to make a square Grid-layout(nested in a Constraint-layout), with all the sides equal to parent width, so that with any device, the user will have the biggest possible square on his screen.
- Then I would like to have another four squares in that first square, which will be Linear-layouts with a background image, that will stretch according to the Grid-layout cell size.
- Ideally, I would like to do this in XML. I am a beginner in android and excuse my maybe obvious question and mistakes in the following code, but I have been spending an awful amount of time on this, without progress. Any help is appreciated.
- Below is my main.xml, where the cells have fixed dimensions. I tried messing with weight and gravity, but was unsuccessful. Just wondering if there is a simple way of making this code do what I want.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/foursquares"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:columnCount="8"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:rowCount="8"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/a1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowSpan="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:background="@drawable/blacksquare"
            android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/a2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowSpan="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:background="@drawable/whitesquare"
            android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/a3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_rowSpan="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:background="@drawable/whitesquare"
            android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/a4"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_rowSpan="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:background="@drawable/blacksquare"
            android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>


    </GridLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main advantage of ***[ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html)*** is allows you to make large and complex layouts with a flat view hierarchy. No nested view groups like inside RelativeLayout or LinearLayout etc. You can make Responsive UI for android using ConstraintLayout and its more flexible compare to ***[RelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative)*** and [***Grid Layout***](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout).

ConstraintLayout allowing you to easily constrain any view to a `percentage width or height`. So i edited your code little bit. Have a look brother, hope this would help you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="16dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/a1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".48"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".3"
                android:background="@drawable/blacksquare"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/a2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".48"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".3"
                android:background="@drawable/blacksquare"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/a3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".48"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".3"
                android:background="@drawable/blacksquare"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/a1"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/a4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".48"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".3"
                android:background="@drawable/blacksquare"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/a2"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/a5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".48"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".3"
            android:background="@drawable/blacksquare"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/a3"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/a6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".48"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".3"
            android:background="@drawable/blacksquare"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/a4"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: thank you my friend, your code works fine! My question was rather simplified. The project is a chess app and I have written a big part of the code already to work with the Grid-Layout. I am looking for a quick-fix, however I might consider working with a different layout, if this is a dead-end. Are there reasons to prefer Constraint-Layout over the Grid-Layout for that purpose?

Comment: If i am not wrong, it flattens the view hierarchy and gives better performance.